# Only One Option in BIOS with Dual Booting

Tags: dual-boot

I'm rather new to dual booting, but I've installed Linux on a total of three machines along with Windows. In the first two, I can go into BIOS and change the boot order so that Windows will launch regularly unless I want to use Linux, and then I can switch the order, because it shows Ubuntu and Windows in the list of options to reorder.

On the new laptop that I just installed Linux onto, it only displays Windows as an option when booting; however, it goes to the Grub screen, allowing to boot into Linux or arrowing down to Windows.

I'm wanting it to give me the two different options, so that I can boot directly into Windows without having to arrow down on that Grub screen.

I created a partition and installed Linux onto that. When I first installed it (what I think might be the issue), I chose the correct partition in which to install Linux, but I think the boot drive was chosen as the Windows partition. I since deleted the Linux partition and reinstalled Linux, making sure to choose the correct partition as the boot disk, but this has not changed anything.
I tried using a Win11 USB to repair and chose to repair the MBR, but that didn't do anything. So my question: is there a way to fix this? I would like for Ubuntu to be an option to boot up from in BIOS so that I can reorder it.

Thanks for any help anyone can give!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in [this page](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/dual-boot-option-not-showing-in-windows-how-to-fix/) that might work.
From the command prompt type: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu yes`.
You should see a message informing you that the operation was completed successfully.

If this doesn't work you can try to use tools like [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to change the dualboot options. If one of the options is missing you can add a new entry and specify a path where the OS is installed.

If it still doesn't work you can [check the page](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/dual-boot-option-not-showing-in-windows-how-to-fix/) and try more of their solutions. I hope this helped you.

Regards,
Domenec.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to reply! Unfortunately, the command prompt solution didn't work, nor did EasyBCD (it only shows the Windows install, and it won't let me add another one). It says this might be due to booting in UEFI instead of BIOS/MBR...I tried looking up how to enable legacy booting, but that does not seem to be an option in my BIOS.